# Does anyone know an existing jQuery solution to this? Rotating banner / Slider question

Tags: jquery, html, slider, banner, rotation

I am looking for a rotating banner system that would allow this:

This would be the first slide:
[image: Slide 1]
And this would be the second slide
[image: Slide 2]

The banner should rotate automatically, but one should also be able to click the different titles, leading to the respective slide.

Per slide, the background image changes, and a different text with link is shown in a semi transparent red div, as you can see. The slides should be HTML, no images.

I've found a whole lot of sliders and accordions, but they don't cut it. Do you know anything that would work or what do you advise to do?

Kind regards,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would build each slide inside of an individual div and then use the jquery cycle plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ to do all of the cycling. You could then bind events to the links inside of the "slides" that cause the cycle to change slides manually.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a solid plan. I will try to build it like that and get back to you for approval ;-)